# Filter out JIRA tickets by id

Tags: jira

Is it possible to create a filter in JIRA that filters out specific jira ids. I have a filter for my scrum board but there are a couple of jiras on there I dont actually care about. I tried the below but the JIRA still appears.

```
and id != MYPROJ-1234
```

Is the ID not the JIRA key? What is the id?

Thanks

Comment: That should work. Can you confirm your JQL works as expected within the Issue search first?

Comment: yep it does. If I do a search for just id = MYPROJ-1234 I get the one result back. If I include it in my scrum board filter it doesnt.

Comment: Dang, not sure. Maybe quotes around the ID string (although that didn't have an effect in my Jira environment)?

Comment: Hi @admdrew yep tried quotes (single and double) and no quotes no change unfortunately (thanks for your help btw)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `id` field is the number that represents the issue in the database, what you want to do is use the `key` instead, like:

```
key != MYPROJ-1234
```

And that should work. As a side note, you can view the ID of the issue by doing:

```
/rest/api/2/issue/MYPROJ-1234
```

And in the JSON Repsonse, you'll see:

```
{
    "id": "82351",
    "key": "MYPROJ-1234",
    ...
}
```

So if you really wanted to, you could then do:

```
id != 82351
```